# how to get string value from one onclicklistner to another onclicklistner?

Tags: android

> I have a button B1 that adds edit text dynamically. Also I have a submit button that takes the value of edit text and send data to the server. Now, how can i get the string value such that when submit button is clicked data of all edit text can be send to server....
>   Thanks in advance

```
 Diagnolist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText ed;

            Integer count = 1;
            List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                ed = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                allEds.add(ed);
                ed.setHint("add diagonis");
                ed.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                addDiagnosis.addView(ed);


            }

            strings = new String[(allEds.size())];

            for ( int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();

            }
```

Comment: You save a reference to all text edits, for instance in a list, then iterate over it when submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Diagnolist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            EditText ed = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            ed.setHint("add diagonis");
            ed.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            addDiagnosis.addView(ed); 
        } 
    });       
    JSONObject stringdata=new JSONObject();
    submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

           if(addDiagnosis.getChildCount()>0)
           {
                for(int i=0;i<addDiagnosis.getChildCount();i++)
                {
                    EditText edittext=addDiagnosis.getchildAt(i);
                    stringdata.put("EditTextValueNo :"+i,"Value:"+edittext.getText().toString());

                    //write your server request sending code here and send the stringdata jsonobject to server.
                }
           }
        } 
    });
```

Here Diagnolist is your button which will add the edittext in your addDiagnosis linearlayout and stringdata is tha jsonobject which will hold the data of each edit text which you can send directly to server and the submitbutton is for sending all edittext values to server.

Answer (score 0):

you already have the value there, `strings = new String[(allEds.size())];`

Use the `strings` value to send to the server

Comment: strings is a local variable used in one oclicklistner .and i want it to be used in another onclicklistner.so getting strings is not accesible in another onclicklistner.

Comment: so, make it global then.. place it at the top of you class

Answer (score 0):

Make it public variable. Declare `public String varName = "";` outside of `onCreate()` function, but still in the class.